# Release a static object, using new()?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, static

I have a WPF Application in .net 4.5
In this application i created a Class named "Client".

On my App.xaml.cs i declare and instanciate a Client object :

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        public static Client obj_myClient;

        private void Application_Startup_1(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {

            obj_myClient = new Client();

        }
    }
```

After the startup, i load all my clients in a DataGrid, and, when i go on a client line ( on the DataGrid), the client properties are loaded in the App.obj_myClient ( with binding).

I can easily modifiy my client an save in the DataBAse.

My Question : When i want to create a new client, i need to "flush" my App.objMyClient object, so i used :

```
App.obj_myClient = new Client();
```

This code compile right, and no crash, but it appear to generate false data in my binding and always strange mistakes ( like the non-fire event changed,etc....)

I think it's related to the  :

```
App.obj_myClient = new Client();
```

Because if i remove this line, the code is better.

What are your advice in this case please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Best regards,

Nixeus

Comment: why u need static object here

Comment: I know my answer will be very bad but.....i don't know ! I used a static variable for the binded, but maybe i could use a non static object !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the client object as static. Convert it to a property.

And that non-fire of event is that when you create a new Client object the subscriptions to the old object are lost and you have to recreate them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your informations ! I will remove the static ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following to avoid the static variable. But it's difficuilt to tell, if it'll solve your issue, since we don't know what it is doing.

```
public class App : Application
{
    public Client obj_myClient;
    private void Application_Startup_1(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        obj_myClient = new Client();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    var someValue = ((App)Application.Current).obj_myClient.WhatEverMethod();
}
```